# Как сделать прогресс бар для загрузки файлов с интернета в python для pyqt5 GUI

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, gui, progress-bar

Нужно написать скрипт который по клику на кнопку установит файл с интернета, но это должен быть прогресс бар, который покажет сколько процентов уже загружено.

Нужен НЕ консольный прогресс бар, а прогресс бар на PyQt5!

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, 
QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import os.path
from threading import Thread
import traceback
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from winreg import *
import os


aReg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"SOFTWARE\Bethesda Softworks\Skyrim Special Edition", 
0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_32KEY)
gPath, _ = QueryValueEx(aKey, "Installed Path")

def download_file(url: str, file_name: str):
    try:
        local_file_name, _ = urlretrieve(url, file_name)
        print(os.path.abspath(local_file_name))
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

    aReg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
    aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"SOFTWARE\Bethesda Softworks\Skyrim Special 
Edition", 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_32KEY)
    gPath, _ = QueryValueEx(aKey, "Installed Path")

    import zipfile

    fantasy_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(sborka.zip)
    fantasy_zip.extractall(gPath)

    fantasy_zip.close()

   os.remove(sborka.zip)
```

...

```
button.clicked.connect(self.downloadevent)
```

...

```
def downloadevent(self):
    url = 'http://sborka.zip'

    file_name = 'sborka.zip'

    thread = Thread(target=download_file, args=(url, file_name))
    thread.start()
```

Comment: Покажите  ваш пример на PyQt5, который у вас есть.

Comment: @S.Nick Прикрепил. Если нужен полный код, могу сбросить.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46825841/4711135

Comment: Не работает для интерфейса. Это консольный плагин!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделал для PySide2 (проверил, работает), но проблем с PyQt5 быть не должно:

**Для PyQt5**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QProgressBar, QWidget, QLineEdit, QPushButton,\
    QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QThread, pyqtSignal
import urllib.request    

class Downloader(QThread):
    # Сигнал о количестве данных (PyQt5)
    preprogress = pyqtSignal(float)
    progress = pyqtSignal(float)

    # fileUrl - url - файла, включая сам файл
    # filename - имя файла
    def __init__(self, fileUrl, fileName):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        # Флаг инициализации
        self._init = False
        self.fileUrl = fileUrl
        self.fileName = fileName

    def run(self):
        # тест на локальных данных, но работать должно и с сетью
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(self.fileUrl, self.fileName, self._progress)

    def _progress(self, block_num, block_size, total_size):
        if not self._init:
            self.preprogress.emit(total_size)
            self._init = True

        # Расчет текущего количества данных
        downloaded = block_num * block_size
        if downloaded < total_size:
            # Отправляем промежуток
            self.progress.emit(downloaded)
        else:
            # Чтобы было 100%
            self.progress.emit(total_size)

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.downloader = None

        self.fileUrl = QLineEdit()
        self.loadButton = QPushButton()
        self.loadButton.clicked.connect(self._loadFile)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()            

        hbox.addWidget(self.fileUrl)
        hbox.addWidget(self.loadButton)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)                                                    
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)                         
        self.bar = QProgressBar() 
        vbox.addWidget(self.bar)

    def _loadFile(self):
        ar = self.fileUrl.text().split('/')
        if len(ar) == 0:
            return
        fileName = f'_{ar[len(ar) -1]}'             

        self._download = Downloader(self.fileUrl.text(), fileName)        
        # Устанавливаем максимальный размер данных
        self._download.preprogress.connect(lambda x: self.bar.setMaximum(x))
        # Промежуточный/скачанный размер
        self._download.progress.connect(lambda d: self.bar.setValue(d))
        self._download.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Дополнение**

```
button.clicked.connect(self.downloadevent)
bar = QProgressBar()

def downloadevent(self):
    url = 'http://sborka.zip'
    file_name = 'sborka.zip'

    thread = Downloader(url, file_name)
    bar.show()
    thread.preprogress.connect(lambda x: bar.setMaximum(x))
    thread.progress.connect(lambda d: self.bar.setValue(d))
    thread.start()
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107594/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-chernin------).