# Как реализовать отображение загрузки файла с определённой ссылки в QProgressBar?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, requests

Есть `ProgressBar`, который я уже реализовал благодаря этой теме: [Тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/786314/%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с помощью `requests` реализовать скачивание файла с определённой ссылки и отобразить процент (процесс) загрузки в этом баре.

```
from LauncherGUI        import GUI
from PyQt5.QtCore       import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import QWidget, QProgressBar, QPushButton, QApplication

class SlowTask(QtCore.QThread):
    updated = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    running = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SlowTask, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.percent = 0
        self.running = True

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            self.percent += 1
            self.percent %= 100
            self.updated.emit(int(self.percent))
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, QWidget, GUI):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        """
        Создание прогресс бара
        """

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self)
        self.progressBar.setFont(font)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 440, 671, 31))
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(44, 177, 128);")
        self.progressBar.setProperty('value', 0)


        """
        Кнопка установить
        """ 

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Franklin Gothic Medium Cond")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferDefault)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('УСТАНОВИТЬ', self)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 440, 151, 31))
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(44, 177, 128);color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_start)

    def toggle_buttons(self):
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(not self.pushButton.isEnabled())

    def on_update(self, data):
        self.progressBar.setValue(data)
        if data == 99:
            self.on_stop()

    def on_start(self):
        self.toggle_buttons()
        self.task = SlowTask(self)
        self.task.updated.connect(self.on_update)
        self.task.start()

    def on_stop(self):
        self.task.stop()
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        self.toggle_buttons()
        self.pushButton.hide() # Скрываем кнопку Установить
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Franklin Gothic Medium Cond")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferDefault)
        self.pushB = QtWidgets.QPushButton('ИГРАТЬ', self)
        self.pushB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 440, 151, 31))
        self.pushB.setFont(font)
        self.pushB.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushB.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(44, 177, 128);color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushB.setObjectName("pushB")
        self.pushB.show() # Показываем кнопку играть

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
 
    mw = Main()
    mw.show()
 
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Или же есть совсем другие удобные модули?

Comment: Такой вопрос уже разбирался: [ТЫК](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1119619/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-python-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-pyqt5-gui)

Comment: @PrinterOMG, Спасибо